# Fortran Class(*)

Tags: fortran, polymorphism

Have written a routine to convert a character to integer

```
Integer :: j
Write (*,*) '# Call str_to_num ("12", j)'
Call str_to_num ("12", j)
Write (*,*) "j: ", j
```

I am using class(*) and getting error

```
Program received signal 11 (SIGSEGV): Segmentation fault.
```

However when I change `Class(*)` with `Integer`, I do get 
`" Subroutine str_to_num"` being printed.

Furthermore, changing to `Intent(inout)` rather than `Intent(out)` gets
the routine to work

```
Subroutine str_to_num(s, num, fmt, wrn)

Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: s
Character (len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: fmt 

Class (*), Intent (out) :: num
Character (len=*), Intent (inout), Optional :: wrn 

Integer :: ios
Character (len=65) :: frmt

Write (*,*) " Subroutine str_to_num"
 Select Type (num)
   Type Is (Integer)
     Read (s, *, iostat=ios) num
   Type Is (Real)
     Read (s, *, iostat=ios) num
   Type Is (Double Precision)
     Read (s, *, iostat=ios) num
   Type Is (Real(Real128))
     Read (s, *, iostat=ios) num
 End Select

End Subroutine
```

Comment: Seems the problem is originating when using Intent(out), when changed to Intent(inout), it continues.

Comment: Which compiler and version? Which checks did you enable? How do you call the subroutine?

Comment: gfortran 4.9. The call is `Call str_to_num("12", i)`

Comment: Wht's `i`? Edit the question to make all environment clear.

Comment: I am thinking it as a bug, as it works with Intent(inout).

Comment: I am trying gfortran 4.9.2, see what happens.

Comment: `intent(inout)` wouldn't result in the situation noted by @HighPerformanceMark.  However, I don't think I agree with the assessment, but also can't answer strongly.  With `intent(out)` the _actual_ argument becomes undefined, but as it isn't allocatable the dummy argument must remain type compatible with it.  [nagfor and ifort are happy to compile/run this.]

Comment: Changing to 4.9.2 hasn't solved the problem. I will be forced to use `Intent(inout)`.

Comment: On intel fortran 2015, it works using intent(inout) and also with intent(out)

Comment: Can one use `Select Type` to distinguish real from integers irrespective of the kind value?